# Unknown Query String in Salesforce Community URL

Tags: community

I am facing an issue with Salesforce community url.
When I login as an external user there is a query string which gets appended to the community url. This has been an issue since some time now.

Before Login:

[image]

After Login:

[image]

Although it is was not causing any major issues till now, we recently added a link with a fragment identifier to the community footer page.

[image]

Now because of this if someone clicks on the link in the footer they are redirected to a page which looks something like this:

[image]

So, once the webpage loads it does not scroll down to the required section in the page, which is a requirement.
I have looked at all the settings i could find regarding the login page and could not figure out why this is happening.

I am on Winter 16 version of Napili salesforce communities template.

Any info on possible causes and workarounds are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Timestamp can't be avoided .Its some internal timestamp thats needed by SFDC for login functionality

Comment: Okay. That can't be avoided then. But it is being appended to every single Page that originated from community. If i Click a link on the community that takes me to another website,the query string is appended to it too. Can we atleast avoid that?

Comment: Adding JavaScript will simply creates unnecessary redirects on load .Not preferred and I would make business understand this

Comment: OKay. Thanks for that.I will just let them know that its not possible